Remove index.php from URL in Nginx
my URLS should be in this format:
https://www.example.com/author/article-title

But Google tries to scan also:
https://www.example.com/index.php/author/article-title

I tried to solve this on Nginx with this rule:
location /index.php {
    try_files $uri/$1/$2 "$uri/index.php\/([a-z-0-9-]{2,})\/([a-z-0-9-]{2,})\/?";
}

If I try the right URL works, if I try the wrong one, the server responds with error 500. I want a redirect 301 to the right URL

"But Google tries to scan also" — Where does Google find such a link? Are you outputting those URLs somewhere…?

I dont know. URLs are generated with Laravel routes. I cant find it

It may depend on whether /index.php/ is also used by your site legitimately, but you could try: location ^~ /index.php/ { rewrite ^/index\.php(.*)$ $1 permanent; }

I solved with (thanks for suggestions):
robots.txt
User-agent: *
Disallow: /index.php

nginx.conf
location / {
    # Redirect requests containing 'index.php' to the same URL without it
    if ($request_uri ~* "/index.php(.*)") {
        return 301 $1$is_args$args;
    }

    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

